# Groovy - SoapUI - Update Headers of Request - Cannot create If statement

Tags: groovy, http-headers, soapui

I am creating a Test Project in SoapUI and need to do the following:

- I have a "Token" Test Suite with 1 Test Case that has: 3 steps that generate the Token for 3 different types of User (Viewer, Admin, Editor) and then one Groovy Script Test Step that takes the Token Header and adds it to all the Test Cases of the Suite.
- For some tests I want to add extra Headers to the Test Steps, but I don't want to delete the already assigned Token Headers.

I had this script created:

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap;

//Get through all the test steps in the project
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites.each {
    suite ->
        suite.getValue().testCases.each {
            q1 ->
                q1.getValue().testSteps.each {
                    it ->
                        if (it.getValue().config.type.equals("restrequest")) {
                            //Get the headers of the current teststep
                            def headers = it.getValue().getHttpRequest().getRequestHeaders()

                            //Append the new header to the existing list
                            headers.put("Header A", "Value A");
                            headers.put("Header B", "Value B");
                            headers.put("Header C", "Value C");
                            //Set the updated header list 
                            it.getValue().getHttpRequest().setRequestHeaders(headers)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

This script updates the Headers to all the Test Cases that I want, BUT also, adds the Headers to the "Token" Test Suite and breaks it.

I want to add an "IF" Statement that will check: If the Test Suite name does not contain "Token" add the extra headers to it. If it contains "Token" leave it as it is. I have the Token Test Suite first in the Project so when calling it automated (through Bamboo) it generates the Token and thus the headers to the rest of the test cases.

I've tried a couple of things but my Groovy skills are amateur and always result in errors.  Can you suggest a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you pointed, have an if condition when suite name is not `Token` in your case.

Here is script, little refactored / groovified:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep

//Define your suite name to ignore
def suiteToIgnore = 'Token'


//Get Project
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->
    if (suiteToIgnore != suite.name) {
        suite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
            kase.testStepList.each { step ->
                if (step instanceof RestTestRequestStep) {
                    //Get the headers of the current teststep
                    def headers = step.httpRequest.requestHeaders
                    //Append the new header to the existing list
                    headers.put("Header A", "Value A");
                    headers.put("Header B", "Value B");
                    headers.put("Header C", "Value C");
                    //Set the updated header list 
                    step.httpRequest.requestHeaders = headers
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you having more in this script apart from what is provided in the answer ¿

Comment: Hi Rao and thank you for your help. I get the following error message when running the script: 
{Code}org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script4.groovy: 8: unexpected token: project @ line 8, column 5. def project testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: project @ line 8, column 5. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)..{Code}

PS: I see you used "kase" in your code. Is that correct, or you meant "case"?

Comment: No I don't have any other code in this Script. Should I rewrite the 2 imports I initially had?

Comment: Sorry about it, it was typo. fixed in the answer now. Can take the updated one please? it was missing `=` after `def project `. Yes, `kase`(used as variable) is correct because `case` is a keyword.

Comment: Changed it with the updated code and now I get error:
{Code}org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script8.groovy: 10: expecting '}', found '-' @ line 10, column 36. project.testSuiteList.each { suite - > ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found '-' @ line 10, column 36. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140) at{Code}

Comment: Read the error and I guess after suite - > it needs: suite ->, without " " between - and >. Correct?

Comment: I used some dumb tool to format the code and it had introduced unwanted  spaces, fixed now. Sorry for not check those minor things.

Comment: If the answer is useful you may consider accepting answer & upvote?

Comment: Already answered and upvoted, thank you for your time Rao, really appreciated.

Comment: You welcome, happy that it was helpful. Have great time.